# About the automatic table column identifier

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, identifier, nstablecolumn

I have create a NSTableView and 2 NSTableColumn in the view. Both of the identifiers of these 2 NSTableColumn set to "Automatic" in Interface Builder.

In the method:

```
(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

I use

```
NSLog(@"%@", [tableColumn identifier])
```

to check the identifier of these 2 NSTableColumn.

I found the identifier of the first column is `AutomaticTableColumnIdentifier.0` but the second is `(null)`.

Is there any reason that the second column doesn't have a identifier?

I have reduced the attribute "Columns" of NSTableView to 1 and increased it to 2 later, so the first column is included in the NSTableView but the second is not.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely the reason:

> I have reduced the attribute "Columns" of NSTableView to 1 and increased it to 2 later, so the first column is included in the NSTableView but the second is not.

If it's causing you problems, set the identifiers in the nib.