# Automatic table column Indentifier in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

After bit of research, I was able to populate the NSTableView with some date via the "identifier way" like you assign unique identifier to each column. However, I would like to now if there is a way to populate NSTableView without providing the identifier to the columns and how?

To be more clear - the use of automatic table column identifier, which is slightly described here: [About the automatic table column identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364680/about-the-automatic-table-column-identifier) and and I find a way how to enumerate or get the index of the column by this expression:

```
//in the objectValueForTableColumn blah blah blah method

int columnIndex = [[aTableColumn identifier] intValue];
return [[myArray objectAtIndex: rowIndex] objectAtIndex: columnIndex];
```

However, the thing is that the columnIndex is equal to 0 in each column. (I have for example 4 columns in NSTableView)

Can you please help me how to display the data without setting the identifier? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all *you should not get the index of the column*, as the columns can be dragged and hence its index can be changed. However you can do as:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

    if ([tableView tableColumns][0] == tableColumn) {
        return [self.array[row] firstName];
    }
    else if ([tableView tableColumns][1] == tableColumn) {
        return [self.array[row] lastName];
    }
}
```

The other way around is to check with the table header cell title. Using this you can decide what value to fill in the column. Something like: (But here you need to set the column header manually)

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

    NSCell *headerCell = [tableColumn headerCell];

    if ([[headerCell title] isEqualToString:@"First Name"]) {
        return [self.array[row] firstName];
    }
    else if ([[headerCell title] isEqualToString:@"Last Name"]) {
        return [self.array[row] lastName];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Also you can opt for Cocoa-Binding, here no need to use identifiers!!!

---

***Edit:***

As you don't have class, infact you are dealing with basic C-array. But the delegate returns `id` so you need to typecast it to some Obj-C object. In following case I use `NSString`. See the screen shot :
[image]

Comment: well, thank you, and what if I have and simple 2D array without the key value coding? like value[x][y] will display in table[row][column] :)

Comment: You mean you have nested table?

Comment: no, just plain 2D array (with no KVC) to display in the NStableView.

Comment: Hey man, the example I show you, is still a 2D. Many Names and each name containing firstName and secondName. What else you need?????

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you, but your example is depend on the Key Value Coding technique. I do not have Objects with firstName and secondName or other properties. The array I have is a simple C array like int[10][10] myArray; so I have matrix 10x10 with some numbers and the way to access them is for example print("%d",myArray[2][3]); so no Key/Value

Answer (score 0):

But the column identifier is not an `Integer`... and therefore your "intValue" will always bring a 0 out of it.

The column Identifier (whether automatic, or provided by the user when defining the table, either programmatically or using the UI editor) is an `NSString`. It is used not only for finding an NSColumn, but also for automatically persisting column attributes in `NSUserDefaults`.

Another wrong assumption - is that the column identifier has to do with its index. It is NOT. Columns can be re-arranged (by dragging them around, or programmatically) so their index can change.

So - to adapt your code sample to working with column identifiers -  I would recommend that you will not work with a 2-dimensional array (with indexes for both rows and columns) but rather use an `NSDictionary` for the per-column information, where the key (`NSString`) will be the column identifier, and the value - the value of the cell you need.

So: indexes for rows, keys for column identifiers, your sample lines would look like this:

```
//in the objectValueForTableColumn blah blah blah method

NSString columnIdentifier = [aTableColumn identifier];
return [[myArray objectAtIndex: rowIndex] valueForKey: columnIdentifier];
```