# Cocoa: Show each array itemset containing multiple items on separate line of tableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tableview

I have been at this for a few days now and cant figure this out.

So, say I have an array:

```
Item # | Name | Price | Discount
1      | Car  | 3000  | 15%
2      | Bus  | 6000  | 5%
3      | .... | 4500  | 0
```

Also I have a table view where I want items to show like the scheme above, but instead what i get is:

```
1     |  1
Car   |  Car
Bus   |  Bus
....  |  ...
```

So the tableview actually repeats only the first row of the Array and prints its contents repeatedly for each consecutive column.

I am just beginning to code so would be nice to hear some advice.
The tableView is linked to sourceData, and made Outlet.

I have the following overrides:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.allData count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return [self.allData objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    [self.allData replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:object];
    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375689/automatic-table-column-indentifier-in-nstableview

Comment: You're missing that you need to select a index in the row of your array, so you get the correct X and Y of your data.

Comment: `-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    if ([tableView tableColumns][0] == tableColumn) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.allData[row][0]];
    }
    else if ([tableView tableColumns][1] == tableColumn)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.allData[row][1]];
    }
    return nil;
}`

Comment: Changed to the above, dont get why it is formatted like this, but anyways. Now my array is workin as it was. its name is allData. Buth when i try to open the tableView I get an exception. unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000029140. also  5   Photography                         0x0000000100002c79 -[Document tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:] + 297    I expect i did something terribly wrong here, all my data is stored as NSStrings in array.

Comment: I am not good with OSX stuff, but i will try to get this working for ya when i get home. Expect an answer in about 10 hours.

Comment: Is the data a NSArray of NSStrings or a NSArray of NSArray of NSStrings?

Comment: the data is NSArray containing only NSStrings

Comment: I heard there is some way to use the ArrayController or do what i need via Dictionary, but I couldnt find, and yes i have been searching for a week now, a completely explained solution. All i know is not to use Cell based tableView and use the new View Based mode. But thats pretty much it... I will wait for any possible replies, whenever they come.

Comment: Did you read the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH1-SW1)?

Comment: And take a look at [TableViewPlayground](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010727-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).